# Why did Lito not take his compromising photos after beating up?

Tags: sense8

In *Sense8*, we have the episode, [What is Human?](http://sense8.wikia.com/wiki/What_Is_Human%3F), where we see Lito (well, with some help) beat up Joaquin. What I cannot fathom is that I would have tied up Joaquin and taken his phone and destroyed it (maybe I would have destroyed all his electronic devices and tortured him and asked whether he had uploaded it on the cloud). It intrigues me that after all the hard fighting, he just let it go? Like what is wrong with these people? Daniela could have escaped when Joaquin was asleep. What was the need to fight if he only wanted Daniela? But when he won the fight, it is natural for anyone to take away the compromising photos. So why didn't he?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it no longer matter for him at that moment. Lito went there to rescue Daniela not to take back he photos, he was even ready to come out of closet. He even kissed a bartender just before it and was ready to tell him he have a boyfriend and not available. And he even allowed Daniela to take there new kisses photos after the rescue.

Now a person who is ready to take a stand for his love doesn't need to destroy the evidences of that love. I know in season 2 he faced the consequences due to photos leak but he didn't want to even try at that moment. And remember he is a actor not a torturer.

And making Daniela escape when Joaquin was asleep will not help him leaving his coward self back. And how do Daniela knows that she can leave now without worrying about photo leaks?

Comment: Ya I completely forgot about that bartender kiss...makes sense.